# MessageBox not displaying the correct output

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to use messagebox to display the output of my function however while the function displays in the terminal it doesn't display in the messagebox. Is messagebox the correct one or is there another function I should be using? I simply want the x words to display on the GUI.

```
#Imports
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from collections import Counter
from tkinter import messagebox
import collections

# Initialize the dictionary
wordcount = {}

#open Macbeth text file
file = open('Macbeth Entire Play.txt', encoding="utf8")
a= file.read()

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__()  # Call __init__() method in parent (tk.Frame)
        
        self.label = tk.Button(self, text='How many words to Sort?', command=self.ask_count)
        self.label.grid(row=0)
        self.open_btn = tk.Button(text='Compute', command=self.ask_count)
        self.open_btn.pack(pady=(30,10))
        self.exit_btn = tk.Button(text='Exit', command=master.destroy)
        self.exit_btn.pack()

    def ask_count(self):
        
        with open('Macbeth Entire Play.txt', encoding="utf8") as file:
            self.file_text = file.read()
        for word in a.lower().split():
          word = word.replace(".","")
          word = word.replace(",","")
          word = word.replace(":","")
          word = word.replace("\"","")
          word = word.replace("!","")
          word = word.replace("â€œ","")
          word = word.replace("â€˜","")
          word = word.replace("*","")
          if word not in wordcount:
              wordcount[word] = 1
          else:
              wordcount[word] += 1
        n_print = int(input("How many most common words are: "))
        print("\nThe {} most common words are as follows\n".format(n_print))
        word_counter = collections.Counter(wordcount)
        for word, count in word_counter.most_common(n_print):
          print(word, ": ", count)
        messagebox.showinfo("The top words are: " == n_print)

        # Close the file
        file.close()
        messagebox.showinfo("The top words are: ")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Count words")
    root.geometry('400x400+900+50')
    app = Application(root)
    app.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you please add the error traceback? It will make out life a lot easier

Comment: `tk.Label.(text='How many words to Sort?').grid(row=0) ` not `self.label(text='How many words to Sort?', command=self.ask_count).grid(row=0)`

Comment: @TheLizzard I fixed all the errors however the GUI doesn't seem to print the same answer as the regular function, do you know why?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the line `self.label(text='How many words to Sort?', command=self.ask_count).grid(row=0)` is causing the error.

In this line, it seems that you are trying to call the `label()` function from `self`, but there is no `label` method in `class Application(tk.Frame)`. Also, Tkinter labels don't have a `command` argument, so you'll have to use a button instead. It is also a good idea to store the button in a variable and call `grid()` on a separate line. This allows you to keep a reference to the button object.

Try replacing that line with this:

```
self.label = tk.Button(self, text='How many words to Sort?', command=self.ask_count)
self.label.grid(row=0)
```

This will create a button and put it inside the application, which is what it seems you are trying to do.

> EDIT:
> It looks like the original question has been modified. To answer the
> new question, replace the line `messagebox.showinfo("The top words are: " == n_print)` with the following:
>
> ```
> top_words = [(str(word)+": "+str(count)) for word, count in word_counter.most_common(n_print)]
> messagebox.showinfo("Top words...", "The top words are: \n" + "\n".join(top_words))
> ```

Comment: Nice catch that it shouldn't be a label but a button instead. I just went from the variable name :D. Also it is better to split it in 2 lines so you can keep a reference to the button object.

Comment: @Andoo thank you, this fixed my GUI Answer however the logic of the initial function program doesn't seem to be translating well into the GUI program it doesn't print out the list when I put in the amount of words I want to see, any idea why? Do I have to create a new variable or a new display in order to show the function properly?

Comment: @FallenDionysus No problem! What error are you getting? For one, in the line `for word in a.lower().split():`, `a` is not defined. Maybe you meant `for word in self.file_text.lower().split():`?

Comment: @Andoo i defined A in my new post, if you can go on that one you can see what I'm talking about and the output

Comment: @FallenDionysus There are 2 code samples in your post. Which one has the wrong output?

Comment: @Andoo, sorry for the late response, I deleted the previous post due to having figured the issue out on my own. However currently I'm trying to display the output for my gui using messagebox, however it doesn't seem to be working, I'll edit the post to display the new code and new question.

Comment: @FallenDionysus Try replacing the line `messagebox.showinfo("The top words are: " == n_print)` with `messagebox.showinfo("Top words...", "The top words are: \n" + "\n".join([(str(word)+": "+str(count)) for word, count in word_counter.most_common(n_print)]))`. Does that give you the output you're looking for?

Comment: @Andoo yes! Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

You wrote this:

```py
class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__()  # Call __init__() method in parent (tk.Frame)
        
        self.label(text='How many words to Sort?', command=self.ask_count).grid(row=0)
```

which doesn't make sense as `self.label` isn't defined. My guess is that you wanted to write

```py
class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__()  # Call __init__() method in parent (tk.Frame)
        
        self.label = tk.Button(text='How many words to Sort?', command=self.ask_count)
        self.label.grid(row=0)
```